# Unexpected output on piped function

Tags: php, functional-programming

I'm trying to emulate the Maybe monad on PHP, and I cannot understand the output from the piped function that I wrote.

The code is inspired by [Eric Elliott's article](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/javascript-monads-made-simple-7856be57bfe8).

php -v // PHP 7.2.19-0 ubuntu0.18.04

```php
<?php   

function pipe_map(...$fns) {
    return function ($value) use ($fns) {

        return array_reduce($fns, function ($prev, $next) {

            return $prev->map($next);

        }, $value);
    };
};

class Maybe {
    private $value;

    public function __construct($value) {
        $this->value = $value;
    }

    private function doesExist() {
        return !empty($this->value);
    }

    public function map(callable $fn) {
        return $this->doesExist()
            ? new Maybe($fn($this->value))
            : new Maybe(NULL);
    }

    public function join() {
        return $this->value;
    }
}

$add1 = function ($value) {
    return $value + 1;
};

$trace = function ($label) {
    return function ($value) use ($label) {
        print_r($label . $value . "\n");
        return $value;
    };
};

$mult2 = function ($value) {
    return $value * 2;
};

$bad_result = function ($value) {
    echo "bad computation happens \n";
};

$maybe3 = new Maybe(3);

$result = pipe_map(
    $trace("Value is now: "),
    $add1,
    $trace("Value is now: "),
    $bad_result,
    $trace("Value is now: "),
    $add1,
    $trace("Value is now: "),
    $mult2,
    $trace("Value is now: ")
)($maybe3);


?>
```

The expected result was something like:

```
Value is now: 3
Value is now: 4
bad computation happens
Value is now: 
Value is now: 
Value is now:
```

But I got:

```
Value is now: 3
Value is now: 4
bad computation happens
```

I expected the functions placed after `$bad_result` function to be called, but apparently they weren't.

When printing the `$result` variable the output is:

```php
print_r($result);

// Maybe Object
// (
//     [value:Maybe:private] => 
// )

var_dump($result->join());

// NULL
```

Could some bright soul illuminate me?

Comment: It happens in PHP 5.x also.

Comment: Once the value becomes null, you always return `new Maybe(NULL);` which doesn't call the function.

Comment: There are several pieces involved, can you not test them in separation? Also, stepping through the code in a debugger should pretty early give you a hint where it's going the wrong way. That said, just a hint, your code is not formatted in a PSR-compliant way, which makes it harder for others to read and thus also to understand.

Comment: Side note: This isn't a monad, just a functor. Your `join` method is actually called `cata`, because it defines the elimination rule of the `Maybe` type. A proper `join` would have to collapse two monadic layers into one, i.e. it has to return a `Maybe`.

Comment: That seems to be the whole point of the `Maybe` class. Once you get an invalid value, you're supposed to stop calling the functions so you don't propagate an invalid input to them. It doesn't distinguish between `$trace` and the functions that perform calculations, so it doesn't call `$trace`.

Comment: You need a way to distinguish functions that should always be called, and functions that should only be called when `$this->value` is not null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all , the expected result should not be something like :

```
Value is now: 3
Value is now: 4
bad computation happens
Value is now: 
Value is now: 
Value is now:
```

This is because in the next call after the `$bad_result` you are calling the `add1` closure which will add 1 to your output `null + 1 = 1` .

So the expected result should be something like

```
Value is now: 3
Value is now: 4
bad computation happens
Value is now:
Value is now: 1
Value is now: 2
```

This is all happens because you are returning `new Maybe(NULL);`

How do you expect to execute the callbacks after the bad computation while you are simply not calling them?

remember , starting from the `$bad_result` callback you are getting null, so each call to the `map` method will always execute the `else` statement which is `new Maybe(NULL);` which call nothing.

You will need to `Maybe($fn(null));` instead, to make sure that you will call your callable for each iterate.

---

To get the exact expected result :

```
Value is now: 3
Value is now: 4
bad computation happens
Value is now: 
Value is now: 
Value is now:
```

you will need to validate the `$value` in your closures, specially the `add1` closure.

something like :

`return !$value ? null : $value + 1;`

Comment: Oh of course, I was not calling them. Jesus I feel dumb now. Thanks for the early response!